# Self-hosted website just shows the router log-in page when using https

Tags: ubuntu, router, port-forwarding, ssl, nginx

As the title says, when I go to my website https://example.com it shows my router's log-in page instead of `index.html`. When I go to a specific page on the website, for example http://example.com/foo.html (notice the `http` instead of `https`) it works just fine. Another note: Just going to http://example.com redirects to the https version, so I have to specify http://example.com/index.html to get the default page.

The site was previously working as intended using nginx, but after messing around with [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) it no longer works. I have since deleted Caddy and reversed to nginx, but it doesn't work as before.

Caddy is a web server that automates getting an SSL certificate. I am not sure how to remove SSL from my site. Maybe by going directly through Let's encrypt? But I don't know how.

I suspect Caddy messed up some settings, but I have no clue as to which and how to fix it.

The website is hosted on a laptop running Ubuntu in my house.

I would really appreciate any help and advice you could give me. Thanks!

NB. I have asked at Server Fault, but it was apparently off topic.

Trimmed content of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/viktor/website;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Trimmed content of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: What's the content of "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"?

Comment: I added it to the main post

Comment: Content of "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"?

Comment: Also added to the post.

Comment: And content of files in "/etc/nginx/conf.d/".

Comment: /etc/nginx/conf.d is an empty directory.

Comment: Make sure you clear your browser cache.  The browser has most likely cached the 301 permanent redirect that Caddy probably used to redirect http://example.com/ to https://example.com/   Browsers tend to be pretty aggressive in caching 301 redirects.

Comment: @heavyd I can't believe it was that easy! That was exactly the solution. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @loading... I'll probably leave this as just a comment since it doesn't actually answer the question (which to me is how to fix your router so it forwards 443 on to your server instead of handling the connection itself), but I'm glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your router configuration to see if you can disable “administration via the WAN port”. Your router can’t do NAT Loopback on port 443 on the WAN interface if it has its own listener open on port 443 on the WAN interface.

If that doesn’t work out, you almost certainly have a buggy router that doesn’t handle NAT Loopback (a.k.a NAT Hairpinning) correctly for port 443.

If you really need to be able to admin your router from the WAN side, see if you can tell it to put its admin UI web service on an alternate port instead of 443. Let’s say you put it on 50443. Then you can connect to your router’s admin UI going to https://example.com:50443/